# webdriverio A request to set a cookie's value could not be satisfied

Tags: cookies, webdriver, phantomjs

this is my code, I want to set cookie, but I get the error message shown below.

```
 await browser.url(`http://xxx.xxx.com`);
 await browser.setCookie({
  name: 'myCookie',
  value: '12sdfdsfsdfsfddsf3',
  domain: 'xxx.xxx.com',
  path: '/',                /* required property */
  httponly : true,
  secure   : false,
  expires  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60)
});
```

this is the error message

```
Unable to set Cookie
running phantomjs
Error: A request to set a cookie's value could not be satisfied.
at cookie("post", [object Object]) - index.js:348:27
at url("http://xxx.xxx.com") - index.js:307:3
```

this is the config

```
{
 capabilities: [
  {
    browserName: 'phantomjs',
  }
 ],
 exclude: [],
 maxInstances: 2,
 sync: true,
 logLevel: 'error',
 coloredLogs: true,
 waitforTimeout: 20000,
 connectionRetryTimeout: 50000,
 connectionRetryCount: 3,
 screenshotPath: './errorShots/',
 screenshotOnReject: true,
 framework: 'mocha',
 reporters: [costomReport],
 reporterOptions: {
  outputDir: './',
  combined: true
 },
 mochaOpts: {
  ui: 'bdd',
  timeout: 30000,
 }
}
```

I have tried using browser.cookie("post", [{...}]), but it does not work too.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share your phantomjs logs, otherwise we can't tell what is going on

Comment: Also please see here: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2900 it is more or less a PhantomJS issue. You should consider up/downgrade your version.